# Instagram-graph-api app review insights api

Tags: instagram-graph-api

I want to get insights on instagram business accounts and their posts that are public for some data analysis and prediction work. I looked over the graph-api documentation but it says that I have to submit an app for review.

I was wondering if there is any other way as I will not have any frontend to my application and only data analysis.

Or if there isn't, is there any demo application that I can submit for review?

Comment: you can submit a video that shows how exactly you want to use the data. try with a facebook page token for a page with a connected instagram business account you own to show that.

Comment: We want to use it for our internal tools, when we get the data then we'll start building tools.

Comment: well, "insights" are only available for accounts you own anyway, and you don´t need review for that...

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. Thanks!